# Using Grep in TextWrangler to move a line up

Tags: replace, grep, textwrangler

I've got some sloppy text that needs to be cleaned up. Somehow random line breaks got inserted in the middle of paragraphs.

```
This is a paragraph
and it got broken into two lines.
```

The manual way to deal with this would be to

1. Place my cursor at the beginning of line 2
2. Hit delete to bring that line up to line 1
3. Hit space to separate the two words that get mashed together by doing this

Is there a way to accomplish this with Find and Replace? I know I can find the offending lines with `^[a-z]` and checking "Case Sensitive", but that's as far as I can get.

I'm just starting to learn how powerful pattern matching can be and I've solved all the other cleanup issues, but this one still perplexes me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` in `linux`

```
cat file
This is a paragraph
and it got broken into two lines.
This line is fine and should be printed.
Here is another
that has been broken.
```

```
awk 'NR>1 {printf "%s"(substr($0,1,1)~/^[[:lower:]]$/?FS:RS),a} {a=$0} END {print a}' file
This is a paragraph and it got broken into two lines.
This line is fine and should be printed.
Here is another that has been broken.
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possibility you could adapt that to be used in TextWrangler or any other program using a powerful Find and Replace function?

Answer (score 0):

If there is really nothing more to be taken care of, search for `\n([a-z])` (**with** find's "Matching" both "**Case sensitive**" and "Grep" **enabled**) and replace with `\1`. (The searched for expression does not have a leading blank, whilst the replacement does actually have one.)